# Verify a Superpowerset

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

A superpowerset (analogous to [superpermutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpermutation)) on \$n\$ symbols is a string over the alphabet \$\{1,2,...,n\}\$ such that every subset of \$\{1,2,...,n\}\$ appears as a substring (in some order). For instance, `12342413` is a superpowerset on four symbols because it contains `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `12`, `13`, `41`, `23`, `24`, `34`, `123`, `241`, `413`, `234`, `1234`.

The lengths of the shortest such strings and some examples are given in this sequence: [A348574](https://oeis.org/A348574)

### The Challenge

Given a string composed of \$n\$ unique symbols (and, optionally, \$n\$), output whether it is a superpowerset on \$n\$ symbols.

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
- Assume only valid input will be given.
- Assume \$n\$ is greater than \$0\$
- Input and output can assume whatever form is most convenient, e.g. the series of symbols can be a string, a list, an integer, a set of n bitmasks, etc, so long as it is indicated in the answer. Additionally, anything may be used as a symbol provided it is distinct from all the other symbols.

### Test Cases

```
In: 1234
Out: False

In: 1
Out: True

In: 11111111
Out: True

In: 123
Out: False

In: 1234512413
Out: False

In: 12342413
Out: True

In: 123424133333333
Out: True

In: 1234567214573126431523674256147325716357
Out: True

In: 122331
Out: False
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice challenge!

Comment: I think a few more test cases, especially ones which give false outputs, would be helpful.

Comment: Must a "superpowerset" always be the one of optimal length, or is (for example) `123424131111111` also valid?

Comment: @pxeger No, sub-optimal strings are fine too. It's just that only the shortest strings are given in that sequence.

Comment: Can the substrings have repeated elements? For example, is 1122334422441133 a superpowerset?

Comment: @AnttiP No, the substring must be one of the permutations of its subset.

Comment: May we assume that the symbols are \$1\dots9\$?

Comment: May I freely choose symbols used? Or is `33333` a valid truthy testcase?

Comment: @tsh Yes, you can.

Comment: Suggested test case: `122331` (false).

Comment: @trotzt - Thanks for accepting my answer...  however, I'd suggest un-accepting it.  2 reasons: (1) the challenge has only been running 12h, so there's still plenty of time for other as-short or shorter answers to appear, and (2) code-golf can be seen as a competition to find the shortest code *within* each programming language, rather than *between* different languages (so a very-short Husk answer isn't "better" than a longer-but-possibly-cleverer answer in a more-verbose language), so it's difficult/impossible to choose the "best" answer...

Comment: @trotzt - ...It's quite normal on this site to never accept an answer at all, so the competition is always open...

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒPḊfƑɓẆṢ€
```

A dyadic Link accepting the alphabet size, `N`, on the left and the candidate string, `S`, on the right as a list of integers that yields `1` if the string is a superpowerset of that alphabet size.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opICHO7rSjk08OfnhrraHOxc9alrz//9/k//RhjpGOsY6JkDSRMdQxzgWAA)**

#### How?

```
ŒPḊfƑɓẆṢ€ - Link: integer, N; list of integers, S
ŒP        - powerset of [1..N]
  Ḋ       - dequeue - removes the empty list
     ɓ    - new chain with swapped arguments:
      Ẇ   -   all sublists of S
       Ṣ€ -   sort each
    Ƒ     - is the dequeued powerset invariant under:
   f      -   filter keep the sorted sublists
```

Comment: @Arnauld, no I left 3 in the argument from trying out some other inputs; I have changed it back to 4. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 90 bytes

```
lambda i,n:f(*i)+2>>2**n
f=lambda a,*i,k=0:1<<(l:=k|1<<a-1)|(i>()and(l>k)*f(*i,k=l)|f(*i))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XU9RasMwDP3vKfQTLGcOzI4HJdQ-yNiPS5vOxHFD7MIGucl-AmO7yE6x28xJnZ89kPQkPUno43t4j69XP39e1MvXLbbV_vfZmf54MmCZb1osLX0QWouy9LtW5ZZhpWWdemz44YCuUd2UiKk4ndBqpMaf0OmOlst40jk6rYtovvDTXkeI5xDBeiBc1JIwwhfLWKio714-cSH5lvyjGeuoEHUtpRBS8tQgzQ4S_K0_nscACpwNEXszoPWRrdcpXSXDmCpICr4PUGkoAoECcBEwuGBewKA3b1tC6fbKPN_jHw)

Takes a list of integers `i` and the integer `n` as arguments. Uses bitmasks to avoid lengthy *frozensets*.

Using one less layer of bitmasks might be a bit clearer, but [costs a byte](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XU9LasMwEN3nFLMxkhwZIlmFYCJfJMlCIXYqLCvGUqCl7UmyMZT2Ij1Fb1NZVjZ9MN_3Zoa5fw-v_vlqp8-LPHzdfFtsf_dG9aezAk1tZRqL3_IW55p8kDWra7tqZeIVzTXt5Kbam0p272y3UwWjOdag7BmbuiNxMEgMWccV5JhO_LTXEXzjPGgLiPFSIIrYbAlzysvFiyfGBXsU_9KEOMp5WQrBuRAsEKhaQYC99admdCDBaOdxrwasrafxOiFRMoyhg1HGtg6KGjKHIAM8CyhccFpAoVcvj4IELK9M0xL_AA).

Comment: What truthy value can `i` have that is not greater than `()`?

Comment: @Neil `i` is always a tuple, so there is no such value. But I want the expression `(i>()and ...)` to evaluate to `False/0` if `i` is empty

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes after inspiration from caird coinheringaahing, and then -1 byte by stealing the I/O idea from [emanresu A's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242529/95126)*

```
-ṁPQ¹Ṗu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/fhzsaAwEM7H@6cVvr///9oQx0jHWMdEyBpomOoYxwLAA)

Outputs a list of an empty list (`[[]]`) if a superpowerset, or a list containing nonempty lists otherwise.

```
      u       # Get uniqe elements of input,
     Ṗ        # and get all subsequences
-             # now remove from this
 ṁP           # all permutations of
   Q¹         # all contiguous sublists of the input.
```

Comment: Just a possibility, but if Husk has an "is contiguous sub list of" builtin, and it works for the empty list, then you should be able to remove both the `t` and the `Q`. I'm not too familiar with Husk's builtin list tho

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing - Thanks for the suggestion. The Husk does indeed have a ```subl``` function to do that (actually it's the same ```€``` function applied to two lists), but I *think* that the problem is that each contiguous sublist needs to be sorted before checking for a match, since the subsets that we're checking might not be in the right order otherwise...

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing - Thanks again: your suggestion prompted me to try swapping sorting for testing all permutations (see edits), which finally led to a different 2-byte golf...

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ŒPŒ!ẇ€SɗƇƑ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opICjkxQf7mp/1LQm@OT0Y@3HJv4/vNyl9tBSpaOTHu6cARSO/P/fREfB9L@hkbGJkYmhsY4CiGVqCGIDAA)

Takes \$n\$ on the left, and a list of integers up to \$n\$ on the right

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 41 bytes

```
Length[{}⋃Union/@Subsequences@#]==2^#2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yc1L70kI7q69lF3c2heZn6evkNwaVJxamFpal5yarGDcqytrVGcspHa/4CizLySaGVdu7RoZR3fxAqgVKxaXXByYl5dNVe1oY6RjrGOSa0OkAkmdFAgRAioBM7QMdEx1QGxTIAkijBuIVSIapSZjjmQbQhmmwPFQDJmQB6IZQpWBVIBMgqkFqQOpMoIrNoQKGIMYtVy1f4HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ÞSvs?Uṗ$F
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnlN2cz9V4bmXJEYiLCIiLCJbMSwyLDMsNCwyLDQsMSwzXSJd)

Returns a list containing the empty list (`⟨ ⟨  ⟩ ⟩`) for truthy and a list containing nonempty lists for falsy.

```
ÞS        # Sublists...
  vs      # Sort each
       $F # Remove from...
      ṗ   # Powerset of...
    ?U    # Unique symbols of input
```

Comment: Very clever use of I/O!  I hope you'll take it as a compliment if I now steal that trick...!

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>83</s> 76 bytes

```ruby
->l,n{!(z=*1..n).uniq{|w|[*z.combination(w)]-l.each_cons(w).map(&:sort)}[1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7ZCoMwFER/pX0pKjFws0LB/ohIUbsFNLEuaDV@u41oHzowcIa5cKfuss/yiJbwUiA9Hb0xCgBj7eNOq/dkexsHI85NmSmdtspor/eTsMD3NH9dc6Mbl3GZVt7p3Ji69ecYknmpDjEQyhAg2IVcXs04EAYb/sGu7UZIAoxLCkQwCpxQIRnhApikhEsQlMtk/TrZwT7iAd/UU7UN@oGrBrfiCw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 84 bytes

```
And@@(Subsequences@s~ContainsAny~Permutations@#&/@Subsets@Union[s=IntegerDigits@#])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYo9C8IwFEX/ilAQhUJ5@ZwKr@jiVhAncYg11Ax9xSYdROxfj9F28cCFey@nM@FuOxNcY2JbxopuiJvjePX2MVpqrEc/7XoKxpGv6DnVdujGkPyePGbrAn9u8HiidJ19eaBgWzvsXevSm12261gPjsKqwLbAFzAucshhIU/7GyGBCZjrX1mYHaUZCKk5MCU4SMaVFkwqEJozqUFxqd8xfgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 98 bytes

```python
lambda i,s:len(f(i))>>s
f=lambda i,*t:i and{1,len(i)>len({*i})or frozenset(i),*f(*t,i[1:],i[:-1])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/LTsMwELz7K6yc7Mig5tEDRu4RqadeuIUcDHXKSo4d2S6iVP0KDlz6df2R4IRAK5WVdi3NzI5nu114tabooe2sC9jvPIp961Vw6mXrPFijoYVA7qaiCG3EU69l@7yWGJjnWhnSEKB0sfCoEX9MGjhgadb7jA0SoIvh2adwoNbhxtkPZeI/kWBpQ9LAoMp4HSe/yWp6uIwEWOAZsnE@SO0VaqKBxmDwmDWswXCEocG6mtVCJMuEgyBpKzui3qRmuip5HXUOOkIpowgrfVavEm7FoCO6mvN6ZL3iTmwIsFa@D6fddw5MIMnp@HU6fiaVFcLFqMzRfmk4zvKiRKtt4FM@NII/yKPb/gJTXeF5cb0cHedZXmb/U2fi0j7Pi6Is86utbw)

Takes a list of numbers and the number of symbols.

In python, you can't have a set of sets, instead you have to use the immutable frozenset. The algorithm is quite simple, just check every substring. To do that, you can use the vararg-sublist trick, where f is called for every sublist of the input in length order. The recursion is stopped when we encounter the empty list. This means that if this is really a superpowerset, then the resulting set will contain \$2^s\$ elements (every subset, except the empty set plus a 1). We can then use a bitshift to check for that condition.

It's possible to replace `frozenset(i)` with `(*{*i},)` for -5 bytes, but I'm not sure if the order of the set expansion is well defined.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES10), 86 bytes

*Saved 14 bytes thanks to @tsh!*

Expects an array of symbols. Returns \$0\$ or \$1\$.

```javascript
a=>(g=a=>new Set(a).size)(a.flatMap(x=>p=[...p,y=1<<x].map(v=>v&y?0:v|y),p=[0]))>>g(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY3NCoJAFEb3PUW4iBmwwTu/EM70BK1ahouhRjFMJcU0encbwWVK3@Iu7jnfvXfb2eb6zOt2X1Y3N6Z6tNqgTPtZutf27FpkMWnyt8PIkrSw7cnWqNem1hdCSB0OGuK4T8jDrzttut1wjA7dZ8ChN6IEY2Myf2K8VmVTFY4UVYZSNHUDoIwH3tj8YotgziKnbAVxAZTDqvEPn7P6SCoKXCgGVHIGgjKpOBUSuGJUKJBMqKk/fgE)

Comment: `a=>new Set(a.flatMap(x=>p=[...p,y=1<<x].map(v=>v&y?0:v|y),p=[0])).size>>new Set(a).size`

Comment: `new Set(...).size>>new Set(...).size` -> `g(...)>>g(...);g=a=>new Set(a).size`

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics math.unicode`, 74 bytes

```
[ dup members all-subsets rest swap all-subseqs [ natural-sort ] map ⊂ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZA9TgMxEIX7PcW7ACttfiU4AKKhQVRRCq8zgMWu17HHIlHkhpJjcpFlbCTCkgKPZH3z5s0U70lpHvz4@HB3f3uNV/KWOgTiIN8@ktX0i2o6sFciDJ6NfUav@KWO1uhhR9@NHvrWWCUnjQ5wnpiPzhvLuKmqUwV5JzSYYY4F0k9/pmmlyUb6s78stJD/cvafPq3LyyushZvCa9HyZCVdpmVxZUe@l73Zl12z4m5EmRdKVRo32EWHnvqWfIDquqsQ25Kwp8AIb8qd1X3ABpJf9EoUiRlbCdbh8@Md2zFTPX4B)

*"Is the power set of the input's alphabet a subset of the sorted sub-sequences of the input?"*

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
â à eÈá d@øX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=4iDgIGXI4SBkQPhY&input=WyIxMjM0IiwKIjEiLAoiMTExMTExMTEiLAoiMTIzIiwKIjEyMzQ1MTI0MTMiLAoiMTIzNDI0MTMzMzMzMzMzIiwKIjEyMzQyNDEzIl0tbQ)

```
â         - unique elements
  à       - combinations
    eÈ    - all?
á           * permutations of that combination
  d@        * any?
    øX        in input U
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
êæIŒ€{K
```

Only takes the string as input. Outputs `[""]` for truthy, and a list with additional items as falsey, which is allowed because of the flexible rule "*output can assume whatever form is most convenient. ... Additionally, anything may be used as a symbol provided it is distinct from all the other symbols.*" (taken from [*@emanresuA*'s Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242529/52210)).
If a truthy/falsey value was mandatory, a trailing `g` (length) could be added, because only `1` is [truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/52210) in 05AB1E.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8KrDyzyPTnrUtKba@/9/QyNjEyMTQ2MA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w6sOL6s8OulR05pq7/8u9umZSgoaJUWlJRmVmkqHVwM5aYk5xalATq3O/2hDI2MTHUMdQyjQAfJB2MTU0MjEEMJEYUABRI2ZuZGhiam5saGRmYmxoamRsZm5iZGpmaGJubGRqbmhmbGpeSwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ê        # Sorted uniquify the digits in the (implicit) input
 æ       # Pop and push its powerset list
  I      # Push the input
   Œ     # Pop and push its substrings
    €{   # Sort each substring
      K  # Remove those from the powerset-list
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: This would be 7 bytes by dropping teh ```g``` and using the same 'list of empty list' output as emanresu A's Vyxal answer (exploiting the rule "output can assume whatever form is most convenient")...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 53 bytes

```
Ｗ⁻⪪θ¹υ⊞υ⌊ι≔⟦⟧ηＦＬθＦＥ⊕ι✂θκ⊕ιＦ⬤κ⁼¹№κλ⊞ηΣＸ²Ｅκ⌕υμ¬⁻…¹Ｘ²Ｌυη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY89a8MwEIb3/oobT6AOdrJ1CqWFQlNMM5YOwlGtI2cp1kfy85WTSQsdT@@Hnnd0Jo7BcK1XR2wB9@RLwsOZKeOioVMailIwlOSwaBCZ5jIjKfX0sEuJJo9f3xqcnD8hAr5bP2WHi2TWe2/O@ObHaGfrsz1KUMOBabSt/aThv6Z@YztmFPVlKYYTdhqeQ/G5PfFqWnmcVAnLEK42Yi9w8pc4XskfG@vcnMI1RJLoR8j3cZ/GT7Z1/gXv0DJUtSkSqrXrN9t@223q44Vv) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes a string as input and outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for a superpowerset, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⁻⪪θ¹υ⊞υ⌊ι
```

Get the unique elements of the input.

```
≔⟦⟧η
```

Start collecting integers representing sets of unique elements.

```
ＦＬθＦＥ⊕ι✂θκ⊕ι
```

For each substring, ...

```
Ｆ⬤κ⁼¹№κλ
```

... if this substring only contains unique elements, then ...

```
⊞ηΣＸ²Ｅκ⌕υμ
```

... collect a bitmask of the unique elements.

```
¬⁻…¹Ｘ²Ｌυη
```

Check that all possible bitmasks were collected.

34 bytes for a specific input format:

```
ＦＬηＦＥ⊕ι✂ηκ⊕ιＦ⬤κ⁼¹№κλ⊞ηΣＸ²κ¬⁻…¹Ｘ²θη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwDIbvPkWOKVTQ6c2TiAfByXDHsUOZdS12retaffyaDhS8hCTfl590SvjOCZPS3XnAs7R9UKgYg3kuxRNPtvNykDbIG2rGoTa6k6g4PDj8M/Y92xuDRI9jFGbCNYeDizbklZmlKk4qJ9RxwMq9pceC4ojsFpXXZF5cwFLbOOFV2F7miJ83MnpCZTmlZsuhWXEgTmQzN1RpU7RtWr7MBw) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses the same algorithm, but takes an integer `n` and a list of integers less than `n` as input.